# Set theory and Proofs

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Proof that the statement is true
For all non-empty sets A and B, A×B=B×A⇒A=B.
I have tried to come up with the logical order but I cannot seem to find it

Comment: What is "the logical order" ?

Comment: logical order of proof

Answer (score 2):

Fix $b_0 \in B.$

If $a \in A$, then $(a,b_0) \in A \times B= B \times A.$ This gives $a \in B.$ Hence we have shown that

$$ A \subseteq B.$$

A similar proof gives

$$ A \supseteq B.$$

Answer (score 1):

Try letting two arbitrary elements belong to each non-empty set. Next, proceed to work with the definition of the Cartesian product. Remember that the cartesian product outputs a set of 2-tuples and is defined as $\{(a,b) |  a \in A , b \in B\}$ for all $a \in A$ and for all $b \in B$. This set can shown to be equal by the given assumption that $ A \times B = B \times A $ under the definition of the Cartesian product. Finally, you should then be able to show that the two sets are equal.